# Function with IF ELSE doesn't work

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a simple function:

```
new_function <- function(x)
 {
letters <- c("A","B","C")
new_letters<- c("D","E","F")

 if (x %in% letters) {"Correct"}
 else if (x %in% new_letters) {"Also Correct"}
 else   {x} 
 }
```

I make a `dataframe` with letters:

```
df <- as.data.frame(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )])
names(df)<- c("Letters")
```

I want to apply the function on the `dataframe`:

```
  df$result <- new_function(df$Letters)
```

And it doesn't work (the function only writes "Correct")

I get this warning:

> Warning message:
>       In if (x %in% letters) { :
>        the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: If the length is greater than 1, use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: And if statement will evaluate whether the part between brackets is TRUE. If you pass a vector of letter to `if (x %in% letters) {"Correct"}`, this will return a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` value. One for each letter.

Comment: @Soren Stilling Christensen: Kindly consider to upvote or accept the answer when someone has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply`:

```
df$result <- lapply(df$Letters,new_function)
```

Output:

```
df
   Letters       result
1        A      Correct
2        B      Correct
3        C      Correct
4        D Also Correct
5        E Also Correct
6        F Also Correct
7        G            7
8        H            8
9        I            9
10       J           10
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your `new_function` with `ifelse` as @akrun suggested. `as.character` converts `x` to character in case it is a factor:

```
new_function <- function(x){
  ifelse(x %in% c("A","B","C"), "Correct",
         ifelse(x %in% c("D","E","F"), "Also Correct", as.character(x)))
}

df$result <- new_function(df$Letters)
```

or with `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

new_function <- function(x){
  case_when(x %in% c("A","B","C") ~ "Correct",
            x %in% c("D","E","F") ~ "Also Correct",
            TRUE ~ as.character(x))
}

df %>%
  mutate(result = new_function(Letters))
```

**Result:**

```
   Letters       result
1        A      Correct
2        B      Correct
3        C      Correct
4        D Also Correct
5        E Also Correct
6        F Also Correct
7        G            G
8        H            H
9        I            I
10       J            J
```

**Data:**

```
df <- as.data.frame(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )])
names(df)<- c("Letters")
```